# How to install two GNU/Linux in dual boot with one under LUKS and the other not?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, luks, gparted

I've been a Linux user for about 15 years. Since the feature existed, I used LUKS to encrypt the partitions on which I was installing Ubuntu.

I have the following issue: when someone else uses my computer, I have to be there to boot it, because only I should know the decryption secret phrase.

To solve this problem, I thought of installing several OS on my hard drive, one on a LUKS encrypted partition (for me) and another on a non-encrypted partition (for others). This with a dual boot that would allow booting either on the encrypted partition or on the non-encrypted partition.

Unfortunately, I was noble able to implement this idea. After manual partitioning under gparted, the installation always fails.

I'm looking for a tutorial that would explain how to install two GNU/Linux systems in dual boot, one of them encrypted and the other one not.

Comment: or you could use a 2nd keyslot for a 2nd passphrase if you trust enough your users to not abuse this.

Comment: The idea is to have the other users as guests, so they don't have to type any password to use (essentially surfing the internet) the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Prepare a partition for `/boot/efi` and a partition for `/boot` in `gparted`

```
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+-----------|
   | Name | Mount point | Flag      | Size | FS    | Comment   |
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+-----------|
   | sda1 | /boot/efi   | esp, boot | 300M | FAT32 |           |
   | sda2 | /boot       |           | 2G   | EXT4  |           |
   | sda3 |             |           |      | EXT4  | Encrypted |
   | sda4 |             |           |      | EXT4  | Clear     |
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+-----------|
```

2. Install clear GNU/Linux on `sda4`
   At manual partitioning step

   - Select `sda1`

     - Format FAT32
     - Flag esp boot
     - Mount `/boot/efi`
   - Select `sda4`

     - Format EXT4
     - Mount `/`
3. Install crypted GNU/Linux on `sda3`
   At manual partitioning step, *check encrypt*

   - Select `sda1`

     - Mount `/boot/efi`
   - Select `sda2`

     - Format EXT4
     - Mount `/boot`
   - Select `sda3`

     - Delete partition
     - Create partition
     - *Check crypt* and enter passphrase
     - Mount `/`
4. Edit grub

   - From crypted GNU/Linux do `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
   - Enable os-prober by uncommenting `#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER`false`
   - Do

```
       sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
       reboot
```

Notes

To have the passphrase asked after kernel selection,

- encrypted GNU/Linux kernels have to be stored on a specific `/boot/efi` partition (`sda2`)
- clear GNU/Linux kernels have to be stored in the same partition as clear GNU/Linux (`sda4`)